# Optimize extracting list from dataframe to create new variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, optimization

I am extremely new to Python. I have a huge dataframe that contains two variables in list format. It has a dimension of 1416631 x 2.

I am trying to extract the first element of the list to create another variable. However, the current code has been running for over an hour to no avail.

Here is a snippet of the dataframe `MH` with two variables, `col` and `PMID` (which is currently empty):

```
col                             PMID
[1, Aged, Adult, Child]
[53, Humans, Kidney Injury]
[22, Diagnostic Imaging, Aged]
```

This is what I want it to look like (2 variables: `PMID` and `col`):

```
col                             PMID
[Aged, Adult, Child]            1
[Humans, Kidney Injury]         53
[Diagnostic Imaging, Aged]      22
```

Here is my code:

```
# extract PMID
for index, row in MH.iterrows():
    MH["PMID"][index] = MH["col"][index][0]
```

This code works on a smaller dataframe, but doesn't stop running on my larger dataframe.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [[1, 'Aged', 'Adult', 'Child'],
                           [53, 'Humans', 'Kidney Injury'],
                           [22, 'Diagnostic Imaging', 'Aged']]})

df['PMID'], df['col'] = list(zip(*df['col'].apply(lambda x: (x[:1][0], x[1:])).values))

#                           col  PMID
# 0        [Aged, Adult, Child]     1
# 1     [Humans, Kidney Injury]    53
# 2  [Diagnostic Imaging, Aged]    22
```

**Explanation**

- [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) allows you to apply any function, including an anonymous [`lambda`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) function on series.
- The [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `(x[:1][0], x[1:])` splits your column of lists into the format you specified.
- [`zip(*x.values)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921872/9209546) unpacks an array of tuples into an array of 2 columns, which are assigned to columns "PMID" and "col".

Comment: wow. what an elegant solution and extremely fast! it ran within 1 minute! wow. may I bother you with what the syntax means? for instance, what do `zip` and `*` and `lambda x` do?

Comment: @sweetmusicality, good questions! I've added some links to my explanation to help you.